# OpenMediaVault SMB/CIFS Share Failed to Enumerate Objects in the Container. Access Denied

Tags: linux, samba, openmediavault

**Good-day Folks,**

I have a small OpenMediaVault (OMV) v6.0.46-5 deployment, running the Proxmox Kernel v5.19.17-1-pve (*so I can have a ZFS filesystem*) to support Windows 10 clients (*primarily*) in a Microsoft Active Directory environment.  OMV is integrated with Active Directory and my goal is to create a non-public share, expose it to the Windows clients via SMB/CIFS, and then allow members of a certain security group (`Domain Admins` in this instance) to be able to create additional folders and manage permissions on those folders from a Windows client.

Thus far, I have been successful, except that even though members of the security group can create subfolders in the SMB/CIFS share from a Windows client, they are unable to manage the permissions.  I keep getting the error:

> Failed to Enumerate Objects in the Container. Access Denied

I came upon [this article in the Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs#Setting_Share_Permissions_and_ACLs), which mentioned that in order to be able to manage share permissions from a Windows host, the user account being used to do this must possess the `SeDiskOperatorPrivilege` privilege. So I followed the guide to grant my `Domain Admins` group this privilege, as well as adding the `acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes` parameter to the share settings via the OMV Web UI. I have rebooted the OMV Server to confirm that Samba is reloaded, but I'm still facing the access denied message when attempting to manage permissions from a Windows client.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**P.S. I have already posted this question via the [OpenMediaVault forum](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/45280-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-access-denied/), but haven't gotten any responses yet, hence my posting it here.**